# Parse.com Contains string or another string?

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I have a array in my Parse cloud for example ["Peter","Steve"] and i want to query this object, but only have one of these two strings (for example @"Peter"). Is there any opportunity to query that? 
Thanks,
Beeke

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The whereKey:equalTo: method, when applied to an array column checks for containment in the array, so...

```
[query whereKey:@"firstNameArray" equalTo:@"Peter"];
```

... will check if `@"Peter"` is in the object's `firstNameArray` column.

**EDIT** - to check whether the array contains any in a set of elements, you can use `whereKey:containedIn:` ...

```
[query whereKey:@"firstNameArray" containedIn:@[ @"Peter", @"Paul" ]];
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay! But I have another problem: I want to check if this array ("firstNameArray") contains the first or the second string from another array. Can you help me?